# iterator_to_array truncated output

Tags: php, iterator, spl

[FROM PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php)

> iterator_to_array — Copy the iterator into an array 
>   array iterator_to_array ( Traversable $iterator [, bool $use_keys = true ] )

It would work with all  [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) Interface but why am i getting wrong input in the following code:

```
$data = array(
  0 => array(
    0 => 1,
  ),
  1 => array(
    0 => 2,
  ),
  2 => array(
    0 => 3,
    1 => 4,
    2 => 5,
  ),
  3 => array(
    0 => 6,
  ),
  4 => array(
    0 => 7,
  ),
);


$it =  new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data));

echo PHP_EOL, iterator_count($it); // 7  total correct
echo PHP_EOL, implode(iterator_to_array($it));  //745  instead of 1234567 
echo PHP_EOL, implode(iterator_to_array($it, true)); //745  instead of 1234567
```

But

```
foreach($it as $v)
{
    echo $v ;
}
```

Output

```
1234567
```

[See online Demo](http://3v4l.org/fYPvo)

Comment: I see you're trying to use `RecursiveArrayIterator`, you should totally drop that and use `array_walk_recursive()` instead =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `$use_keys` is true by default (since 5.1), clobbering your array keys as it's being flattened. You need to disable the setting like this:

```
print_r(iterator_to_array($it, false));
//                             ^^^^^
```

If you're running PHP < 5.2.1 you're basically screwed ;-)